# Grep for possible results

Tags: grep

I'm trying to grep for possible matches to,

```
ex****e
```

So anything with ex at the start and e at the end with 4 characters inbetween, how could I do this?

Comment: please clarify if you are looking to match words or whole lines... in other words, adding sample input lines and expected output helps..

Answer (score 11):

The regular expression operator that matches a single character is `.`. That's similar to `?` in shell wildcards. `*` itself matches any number of the preceding thing in regular expressions (for instance, `a*` matches any number (including 0) of `a`s), and any number of characters in shell wildcards.

POSIXly, to find lines that match e`x`actly on that:

```
grep -xE 'ex.{4}e'
```

Or:

```
grep -x ex....e
```

Or:

```
grep -x 'ex.\{4\}e'
```

The second of which being the most portable. `grep '^ex....e$'` would even work in the original implementation in Unix Version 4 (1973); however `-x` was added in Unix Version 7 (1979) and is universal nowadays so you can rely on that one.

Extended regular expressions were added in `egrep` in V7 as well but initially without the `{x,y}` interval operators. That operator was added as `\{x,y\}` for `grep` but often not in `egrep` as that would have broken backward compatibility. In the early nineties however, POSIX introduced the `-E` option of `grep` to merge in the `egrep` functionality into `grep` and requires it support `{x,y}` and `egrep` is now deprecated.

However, you still occasionally find some `grep` implementations that don't support `-E` or `egrep` ones that don't support `{x,y}` like the `/bin/grep` and `/bin/egrep` of Solaris (where you need to use `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep` instead).

Beware that some `grep` implementations are not multibyte aware and their `.` regexp operator may match on each byte of a multibyte character like the non-ASCII UTF-8 characters).

```
$ $ locale charmap
UTF-8
$ echo extrême | busybox grep -x ex....e 
$ echo extrême | gnu-grep -x ex....e
extrême
$ echo extrême | busybox grep -x ex.....e
extrême
```

As the ê character is made of two bytes in UTF-8, `extrême` is 7 characters, but 8 bytes:

```
$ printf %s extrême | wc -cm
      7       8
```

Comment: "early nighties" - Freudian _slip_?

Answer (score 2):

With the following  regex :

```
^ex.{4}e$
```

Ex :

```
$ grep -E '^ex.{4}e$' <<< 'ex****e'
```

or

```
$ grep '^ex.\{4\}e$' <<< 'ex****e'
```

### Output :

```
    ex****e
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic pattern suggested by @stéphane-chazelas:

```
grep -xE 'ex.{4}e'
```

will find any line consisting soley of 'e', 'x', any 4 chars, and 'e' and no white space due to the switch '-x' , equivalent to @gilles-quenot's suggestion of

```
grep -E ^ex.{4}e$
```

However, OP wanted "anything with ex at the start and e at the end with 4 characters inbetween", so that would include lines with non-matching content and matching content together. In order to get that, you would need the pattern,

```
    grep -E 'ex.{4}e'
```

Quotes to prevent shell bracket expansion.